# Eclipse and SVN project on a Windows network drive

Tags: eclipse, svn, unc, network-drive

Configuration:

Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 Professional
Subclipse 1.10.2 (org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group)
Subversion Client Adapter 1.10.0 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group)
Subversion JavaHL NLA 1.8.3 (org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.feature.feature.group)
CollabNet Merge Client 4.0.1 (com.collabnet.subversion.merge.feature.feature.group)

This is a PHP project that should reside on `\\WEBSERVER\testing\htdocs` (Ubuntu 12.04-LTS w/ Apache).

Symptoms:

Trying to import the project from SVN by checking out, several undesirable things happen, the worst of which is that upon checkout completion, *all the files sport a question mark* and don't show SVN info (the project itself has [] instead of [reponame]).

If I try to "add to version control" (which I know is wrong, but bear with me) I get "SVN synchronization info has become corrupt or is missing". Committing gets "There is nothing to commit, you made no changes". Changing a file and committing **gets the same answer**.

Meanwhile, TortoiseSVN shows the folder as updated, can update, commit, delete etc. as advertised, and the file I just changed and that Eclipse said hasn't changed is shown by TSVN as having changed, as expected.

Moreover, Eclipse is disastrously sluggish in handling any operations - I guess that every time I click (almost) anywhere, it tries to check the whole SVN tree and stops responding for a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing like this happens to me on Linux. So I put my thinking cap on and guessed that the problem might lie in the UNC path syntax. I connected a network drive as T: from `\\WEBSERVER\testing`, and lo and behold, everything worked flawlessly on the first attempt.
Yet, I found nothing on the docs saying I couldn't use a UNC as a path. Is this something I should have been aware of?